# templateUrl is not working in production mode

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using webpack. I have followed all the steps that are given in angular.io related to webpack. In development mode it works fine but when I am using it in production mode templateUrl is not working. When I copy and paste my code of html and use it as template it works fine. How to make it work?

My base url is < base href="/newsystem/ >
After bundling script tag is < script src="app.js" >

My templateUrl is app/mycomponent.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with templateUrl. It was working on localhost but didn't let me the production build.

I've resolve it removing module.id from the Component decorator and then I could build the production files.

Comment: there are no any module.id in component decorator

Answer (score 0):

When bundling, webpack does not bundle the required html file. So there is no html file bundled. So for this we have to use

template: require('./myfile.html');

By using this process we are putting this html file inside template during bundling process. And we can use relative path freely.